# Passing parent id to a function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass parent id of the child in onclick function but I am unable to do it, however I know how to get parent id of a child element. Here is my code can someone correct it.

```
<div id = "test">
$('#test-'+result[i][1]).append('<div class = "box-content-2" onclick = "Addfriend('+ result[i][1]+','$(this).parent().attr('id'))" id = "box2-'+result[i][1]+'">Add Friend</div>');
</div>
```

I think there is something wrong with my syntax. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id = "test">

</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#test').append('<div class = "box-content" id = "box2">Add Friend</div>');

        $("#box2").click(function() {
            alert( $(this).parent().attr('id') );
        })

    });
</script>
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/yujceqz2/) is demo.